# Levar para o PHP o coteudo de uma div

Tags: php, html, jquery

Não estou conseguindo levar o conteúdo de uma div para o PHP com o Jquery.

Qual seria me problema?

Meu código

Html

```
<form role="form" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="id_oquefizemos" name="id_oquefizemos" class="form-control" value="">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12">Título</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" name="titulo" value="" placeholder="Título Categoria" class="form-control form-control-line">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="example-email" class="col-md-12">Imagem</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-line" name="foto_oquefizemos" id="foto_oquefizemos">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="wmd-panel">
                            <div id="wmd-button-bar-0" class="wmd-button-bar">
                                <div id="wmd-button-row-0" class="btn-toolbar">
                                    <div class="btn-group wmd-button-group1" id="wmd-button-group1-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-bold-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Bold - Ctrl+B">
                                            <i class="fa fa-bold"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-italic-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Italic - Ctrl+I">
                                            <i class="fa fa-italic"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group wmd-button-group2" id="wmd-button-group2-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-link-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Link - Ctrl+L">
                                            <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-quote-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Blockquote - Ctrl+Q">
                                            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-code-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Code Sample - Ctrl+K">
                                            <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-image-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Image - Ctrl+G">
                                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group wmd-button-group3" id="wmd-button-group3-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-olist-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Numbered List - Ctrl+O">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-ulist-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Bulleted List - Ctrl+U">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-heading-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Heading - Ctrl+H">
                                            <i class="fa fa-header"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-hr-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Horizontal Rule - Ctrl+R">
                                            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group wmd-button-group4" id="wmd-button-group4-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-undo-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Undo - Ctrl+Z"
                                            disabled="">
                                            <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="wmd-redo-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Redo - Ctrl+Y"
                                            disabled="">
                                            <i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group wmd-button-group5 pull-right" id="wmd-button-group5-0">
                                        <button class="btn" id="wmd-help-button-0" title="" data-original-title="Markdown Editing Help">
                                            <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <textarea name="texto" id="wmd-input-0" class="form-control editor wmd-input" rows="10"></textarea>
                            <div id="wmd-preview-0" class="wmd-preview"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar Categoria " class="btn btn-default">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {

            // $("textarea#pagedownMe").pagedownBootstrap();

            $("textarea#pagedownMeDangerously").pagedownBootstrap({
                'sanitize': false,
                'help': function () { alert("Do you need help?"); },
                'hooks': [
                    {
                        'event': 'preConversion',
                        'callback': function (text) {
                            return text.replace(/\b(a\w*)/gi, "$1");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'event': 'plainLinkText',
                        'callback': function (url) {
                            return "This is a link to " + url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, "");
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });





        })();

        $(function(){
   $("#cadastrar").click(function(){
       var conteudo = $("#wmd-preview-0").text(); //<----
       $.post('dicas_categoria.php', {
           texto_descricao: conteudo
       }, function(response){
           // Aqui ficará a lógica que será executada quando sua
           // requisição for enviada e a página PHP te der uma resposta
       });
   });
})



    </script>
```

Php

```
<? echo $_POST['nome']; ?>
```

tentei assim mas também não deu

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){ var nome = $('.wmd-preview').html(); });
```

Comment: `<div>` não possui `val`, mas conteúdo. Troque `val()` por `html()`. É trivial que você leia a documentação de uma função antes de utilizá-la.

Comment: não funcionou ainda, troquei como vc falou val() por html()

Comment: Se está mandando `nome: conteudo` para o PHP, por que nele você fez `$_POST['conteudo']` ao invés de `$_POST['nome']`?

Comment: Troquei o $_POST['conteudo'] por $_POST['nome'] mas tbm nao deu certo

Comment: Então faça por partes, primeiro certifique-se que `conteudo` está recebendo o valor desejado, depois faça a requisição POST com um valor conhecido e certifique-se que está chegando no PHP, para finalmente enviar o conteúdo pela requisição.

Comment: essa seria minha dúvida, como faria na prática?

Comment: tentei assim mas tbm nao deu $("#form1").submit(function(){ var nome = $('.wmd-preview').html(); });

Answer (score 2):

Está quase la, mas você precisa acessar o texto de forma diferente, utilizando o método `.text()` do `jquery`

```
$(function(){
   $("#cadastrar").click(function(){
       var conteudo = $("#wmd-preview-0").text(); //<----
       $.post('dicas_categoria.php', {
           nome: conteudo
       }, function(response){
           // Aqui ficará a lógica que será executada quando sua
           // requisição for enviada e a página PHP te der uma resposta
       });
   });
})
```

Mais informações:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Como eu levo o valor para o PHP? Utilizei o $_POST['conteudo'] e também o $_POST['nome'], mais não deu certo

Comment: Com `$_POST['nome']` deveria funcionar. Tem certeza que o post está sendo executado? Que o jQuery está rodando? Abre o console do seu navegador e vê se não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: editei minha pergunta exatamente como está meu formulário e jquery, poderia olhar se tem algum erro? o jquery roda sim, pois tem outras coisas que o jquery funciona no mesmo código. No console nao retorna nenhum erro

Comment: Se estiver usando o chrome, vai abre seu console, vai em Network > XHR e vê se está enviando o request... Caso esteja, abra ele e verifica quais dados estão sendo enviados e qual a resposta do servidor.